# Redistribute a list of merchants_id so each user receives different set of merchants but equal in number - Python

Tags: python, pandas

*Update: This can not be solved 100% since the number of merchants each user must receive is different. So some users might end up getting the same merchants as before. However, is it possible to let them get the same merchants, if there are not any other different merchants available?*

I have the following excel file:

[image]

What I would like to do is to redistribute the merchants (Mer_id) so each user (Origin_pool) gets the same number of merchants as before, but a different set of merchants. For example, after the redistribution, Nick will receive 3 Mer_id's but not: 30303, 101020, 220340. Anna will receive 4 merchants but not 23401230,310231, 2030230, 2310505 and so on. Of course, one merchant can not be assigned to more than one person.

What I did so far is to find the total number of merchants each user must receive and randomly give them one mer_id that is not previously assigned to them. After I find a different mer_id I remove it from the list, so the other users won't receive the same merchant:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df=pd.read_excel('dup_check_origin.xlsx')
dfcounts=df.groupby(['Origin_pool']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
Origin_pool=list(dfcounts['Origin_pool'])
counts=list(dfcounts['counts'])
dict_counts = dict(zip(Origin_pool, counts))

dest_name=[]
dest_mer=[]

for pool in Origin_pool:
    pername=0
    #for j in range(df.shape[0]):
        
    while pername<=dict_counts[pool]:
            rn=random.randint(0,df.shape[0]-1)
            rid=df['Mer_id'].iloc[rn]

            if (pool!=df['Origin_pool'].iloc[rn]):
                #new_dict[pool]=rid
                pername+=1
                dest_name.append(pool)
                dest_mer.append(rid)
                df=df.drop(df.loc[df['Mer_id']==rid].index[0])
```

But it is not efficient at all, given the fact that in the future I might have more data than 18 rows.

Is there any library that does this or a way to make it more efficient?

Comment: I'm not sure you can always do this: If Anne has one `merchant_id` and Bob has two, you'll have a problem. Once you check for this specific case, then you could just shift all your merchant IDs by the maximum number of IDs associated with a single user (assuming all a user's entries sit together, as in your example). *Edit:* In your case George has 6 IDs, so cycle the merchant IDs by 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several days after your question, but I think it's a bullet proof code.
You can manage to create a function or class with the entire code. 
I only created one, which is a recursive one, to handle the leftovers.

There are 3 lists, initialized at the beginning of the code:
pairs      -> it returns your pool list (final one)
reshuffle -> it returns the pairs pool generated randomly and already appeared at pool pairs in the excel
still     -> to handle the repeated pool pairs inside the function pullpush

The pullpsuh function comes first, because it will be called in different situations.

The first part of the program is a random algorithm to make pairs from mer_id(merchants) and origin_pool(poolers).
If the pair is not in the excel than it goes to the pairs list, otherwise they go to the reshuffle list.

Depending on the reshuffle characteristics another random algorithm is called or it will be processed by pullpush function.

If you execute the code once, as it is, and print(pairs) you may find a list with 15, 14 any more pool pairs lesser than 18.
Then, if you print(reshuffle) you will see the rest of the pairs to make 18.
To get the full 18 matchings in the pairs variable you must run:
pullpush(reshuffle).

The output here was obtained running the code followed by: 
pullpush(reshuffle)

If you want to control that mer_id and origin_pool should not repeat for 3 rounds, you can load other 2 excels and split 
them into oldpair2 and oldpair3.

[[8348201, 'Anna'], [53256236, 'Anna'], [9295, 'Anna'], [54240, 'Anna'], [30303, 'Marios'], [101020, 'Marios'], [959295, 'Marios'], [2030230, 'George'], [310231, 'George'], [23401230, 'George'], [2341134, 'Nick'], [178345, 'Marios'], [220340, 'Marios'], [737635, 'George'], [[2030230, 'George'], [928958, 'Nick']], [[5560503, 'George'], [34646, 'Nick']]]

The code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import random
    df=pd.read_excel('dup_check_origin.xlsx')
    oldpair = df.values.tolist() #check previous pooling pairs

    merchants  = df['Mer_id'].values.tolist() #convert mer_id in list
    poolers    = df['Origin_pool'].values.tolist() #convert mer_id in list

    random.shuffle(merchants) #1st step shuffle

    pairs     = [] #empty pairs list
    reshuffle = [] #try again   
    still     = [] #same as reshuffle for pullpush  

    def pullpush(repetition):

        replacement  = repetition #reshuffle transfer

        for re in range(len(replacement)):
            replace = next(r for r in pairs if r not in replacement)
            repair      = [[replace[0],replacement[re][1]],
                          [replacement[re][0],replace[1]]]
            if repair not in oldpair:
                iReplace = pairs.index(replace)#get index of pair
                pairs.append(repair)
                del pairs[iReplace] # remove from pairs
            else:
                still.append(repair)    


        if still:
            pullpush(still) #recursive call


    for p in range(len(poolers)):#avoid more merchants than poolers
        pair = [merchants[p],poolers[p]]            
        if pair not in oldpair:
            pairs.append(pair)              
        else:
            reshuffle.append(pair)      

    if reshuffle:
        merchants_bis = [x[0] for x in reshuffle]
        poolers_bis   = [x[1] for x in reshuffle]

        if len(reshuffle) > 2: #shuffle needs 3 or more elements
            random.shuffle(merchants_bis)
            reshuffle = [] #clean before the loop

            for n in range(len(poolers_bis)):
                new_pair = [merchants_bis[n],poolers_bis[n]]
                if new_pair not in oldpair:
                    pairs.append(new_pair)              
                else:
                    reshuffle.append(new_pair)
                    if len(reshuffle) == len(poolers_bis):#infinite loop
                        pullpush(reshuffle)

        # double pairs and different poolers
        elif (len(reshuffle) == 2 and not[i for i in reshuffle[0] if i in reshuffle[1]]):
            merchants_bis = [merchants_bis[1],merchants_bis[0]]
            new_pair      = [[merchants_bis[1],poolers_bis[0]],
                            [merchants_bis[0],poolers_bis[1]]]
            if new_pair not in oldpair:
                pairs.append(new_pair)
            else:
                reshuffle.append(new_pair)
                pullpush(reshuffle)

        else: #one left or same poolers
                pullpush(reshuffle)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution using dictionaries and lists, i print the result, but you can create a new dataframe with that.

```
from random import shuffle
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('dup_check_origin.xlsx')
dpool = {}
mers = list(df.Mer_id.unique())
shuffle(mers)
for pool in df.Origin_pool.unique():
    dpool[pool] = list(df.Mer_id[df.Origin_pool == pool])
for key in dpool.keys():
    inmers = dpool[key]
    cnt = len(inmers)
    new = [x for x in mers if x not in inmers][:cnt]
    mers = [x for x in mers if x not in new]
    print(key, new)
```